# bash parameter expansion ${parameter:-SUB} vs ${parameter-SUB}

Tags: bash

I see some bash scripts (on GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)) with a parameter substitution like

```
function foo() {
  local x=${1-XYZ} ##### (1) 
  echo "x=${x}."
}
foo ####### this prints x=XYZ
foo ABCD ###### this prints x=ABCD
```

More commonly I see at (1) `x=${1:-XYZ}` and I can find it also described in the Bash reference pages [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-parameter-expansion). Are both correct, or is something else also happening in the background and it might fail in some circumstances?

It does not have to be `$1` - so long as the variable in `${XX-sub}` is not defined, it picks the substitute.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `value` is not set, use `default`, otherwise, use `value`:

```
var=${value-$default}
var=${value:-$default}   # ':' use default even if value declared and empty/null
```

e.g (missing command line parameters):

```
value=
var=${value-$default}     # not set
var=${value:-$default}    # set to $default
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `-` uses the alternate value if the parameter is unset (i.e. not defined), and `:-` uses it is unset OR null (i.e. set to the empty string). For example:

```
$ foo() {
> echo "Argument 1 with :- is '${1:-altval}', with just - is '${1-altval}'"
> echo "Argument 2 with :- is '${2:-altval}', with just - is '${2-altval}'"
> }
$ foo ""
Argument 1 with :- is 'altval', with just - is ''
Argument 2 with :- is 'altval', with just - is 'altval'
```

Here I passed one (empty) argument to the function, so `$1` was set to null, but `$2` was unset.

Answer (score 0):

`${var-word}` returns "word" if `var` is undefined. If not, returns ${var}.
`${var:-word}` returns "word" if `var` is null or undefined. If not, returns ${var}.

You can easily check the difference with this sample script.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=""  ## var1 is Null
#var2=   ## var2 is undefined
var3="value3"  ## var3 is set

echo '${var1}': ${var1} "(NULL)"
echo '${var2}': ${var2} "(Undefined)"
echo '${var3}': ${var3}

echo '${var1-foo}': ${var1-foo}
echo '${var2-foo}': ${var2-foo}
echo '${var3-foo}': ${var3-foo}

echo '${var1:-foo}': ${var1:-foo}
echo '${var2:-foo}': ${var2:-foo}
echo '${var3:-foo}': ${var3:-foo}
```

This script outputs.

```
${var1}: (NULL)
${var2}: (Undefined)
${var3}: value3
${var1-foo}:
${var2-foo}: foo
${var3-foo}: value3
${var1:-foo}: foo
${var2:-foo}: foo
${var3:-foo}: value3
```