# Need help understanding how this variable is being formatted or manipulated

Tags: bash, variables

I have a function I want to use to hopefully mute the volume but I don't understand the last part of it.

```
volume=`dbus-send --print-reply=double --session --reply-timeout=500 --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:"org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player" string:"Volume" ${0:+double:}0`
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
volume="$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$volume")"
```

I don't understand this part...

```
${0:+double:}0
```

I don't even have the slightest idea.  It must be manipulating or formatting stdin ($2) in some way?

I tested it..

```
#!/bin/bash

v=0    
echo "${v:+double:}$v"    
exit 0
```

and get..

```
double:4
```

which doesn't help my understanding of what is going.

Comment: Try `v=` and `v=242`. Help? See also https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: I get `double:242`.  It doesn't help.  Ooops I'm reading your reference now.

Comment: Ok so if stdin (2=arbitrary) is set then use "double:" and the output becomes "double:arbitrary".  If stdin is not set then it just outputs nullstringnullstring?  Sadly I don't have more context or info on this function but at least I know the mechanics of that part.

Comment: @deanresin: See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147033/bash-parameter-expansion-parameter-sub-vs-parameter-sub, it should help you